# openni_tracker-x_y_z-coordinates

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everybody

I have running openni_tracker in Xtion pro live, I can see all the frames in rviz.

My issue now is that I would like to get the (x,y,z) coordinates.

Any ideas,

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64054/openni_tracker-x_y_z-coordinates/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, please see [my answer to your other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/64047/openni_tracker/?answer=64120#post-id-64120).

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-04**:
Thank you, I saw it and now is working quite nice :)

**Comment by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) on 2013-06-04**:
Perfect, glad it worked! Can you accept the answer (by clicking the grey circle with check mark on the left), so the question can be closed? Regards, Philip